# Spring KafkaTemplate: how to send all list objects or none of them

Tags: spring-kafka

Here is a little example:

```kotlin
list.forEach { proto ->
    kafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTopics.TOPIC_NAME, proto)
}
```

Is there any way to make it atomicity? I want to send all messages or none of them. And of course I'd like to get a call result

As I get it, it's possible to lose some of the messages, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this API for that logic:

```
/**
 * Execute some arbitrary operation(s) on the operations and return the result.
 * The operations are invoked within a local transaction and do not participate
 * in a global transaction (if present).
 * @param callback the callback.
 * @param <T> the result type.
 * @return the result.
 * @since 1.1
 */
@Nullable
<T> T executeInTransaction(OperationsCallback<K, V, T> callback);
```

So, your loop has to be wrapped into this `executeInTransaction()`.

You might also need to play a bit with the result of `send()` and compose them all via `CompletableFuture.allOf().join()`.

Comment: You also need to enable transactions in the producer factory in order to be able to use this method. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions